# Dynamic menu with symfony in template

Tags: php, dynamic, symfony1, menu

I'm building a symfony website and I've my own code to build dynamically a menu with subitems. Right now I print it with a bit of twig code inside the base.html.twig file (master layout). The problem is when I need to pass the array with the items of the menu. I'm actually passing it to the render method of a single controller but obvsiously when I switch page I get a non-existent variable. How can I have a single location to put my php code to build the menu array and execute it every time a page is rendered?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put your menu-creating logic in a new controller, and use twig's `{% render %}` to include it in your page. See [embedding controllers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html).