# symfony 3 menu asking for session

Tags: twig, symfony

I'm starting to learn symfony3 and I face a problem I can't solve.

I have a `nav` menu in my `base.html.twig` file, and it changes with some `$_SESSION` variables.

For instance, let's say I want to make a link which redirects to `path/to/myProfile` if the user is connected or to `path/to/connection` if the user is not, whatever the content of the page is.

I could add a `{% block menu %}`, pass a `isConnected` variable to it and make some `if/else` to change the url and text of the link, but since all pages should have the same menu, I'd have to add the same code to every controller I make.

How can I change the parent template before calling any controller ?

In flat php, I used this in my index.php and it works really fine :

```
<?php
$profil_link = isset($_SESSION["login"])?'<a href="profil">Profil</a>':'<a href="connexion">Connexion</a>';
$twig->addGlobal("profil_link", $profil_link);
```

I saw a SO post ([Dynamic menu with symfony in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234530/dynamic-menu-with-symfony-in-template)), but the link in the answer is dead and I cannot find anything about the twig `{% render %}` function (I reckon it was a symfony2 function). Is it related to my problem ?

EDIT : tried to clarify my problem...

Comment: not sure of what you want to do. can you edit and explain better ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to make it clearer but let's try.

Comment: @t-n-y is that better ?

Comment: If you want to insist on making things harder than they have to be then the render function might indeed be what you want: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have do to this in php if you use twig.

you can simply check if your user is connected with twig like that

```
{% if app.user %}
   <a href="{{ path('logged_path') }}">Profil</a>
{% else %}
   <a href="{{ path('login_path') }}">Connexion</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. Yes, it would be OK for my example, but it wont be if it depends on variables other than a connected user (which I don't know yet). Moreover, I find it rather illogical to decide which link to show in a view, since it requires some computing.

Comment: Maybe you should ask for your real need because i don't know what you really want. You asked for login/profile, this is how we do it in twig. Maybe you need something else but i can't guess alone.
You should also avoid using $_SESSION, symfony provide $request->getSession();

Comment: sorry, it's quite hard to formulate a question about a framework you dont master 100%.

Comment: simply ask for what you want, don't try to find generic cases that don't fit your needs